# Add remote images to PhpSpreadseet cell

Tags: php, image, phpspreadsheet

There is a simple two-column table on a website: product name and product image. It's very easy to render in HTML.
The task would be creating an Xlsx file with these columns.
The images are not stored locally but all of them are remote images with full URL.
The export contains ~100-200 rows.

I tried to create a resource with imagecreatefromjpeg and adding it with MemoryDrawing but it took a huge amount of resources.
I tried with Html helper's toRichTextObject and a simple  tag but got empty result.

How is it possible to add a remote image to a PhpSpreadsheet cell? It doesn't need working offline, it's fine to load the remote images when the file is opened.

Comment: you don't have 36 solutions upload with file_put_contents the image on the server then you insert it in your xlsx file

Comment: @FabriceFabiyi wdym? Something like [this example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php#125653), combined with the usual [drawing](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#add-a-drawing-to-a-worksheet)?

Comment: yes is that @OmarTrkzi

Comment: Great, it worked! Thank you @FabriceFabiyi I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example how add image to your excel export:

```
$spreadsheet = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet();

$drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
$drawing->setName('Paid');
$drawing->setDescription('Paid');
$drawing->setPath('/images/image-1.png'); // put your path and image here
$drawing->setHeight(30);
$drawing->setCoordinates('A5');
$drawing->setOffsetX(110);
$drawing->setRotation(25);
$drawing->getShadow()->setVisible(true);
$drawing->getShadow()->setDirection(45);
$drawing->setWorksheet($spreadsheet->getActiveSheet());
```

Comment: Is there a way of looping the images using foreach, for instance, if one is exporting images from a database?

Answer (score 1):

As @*FabriceFabiyi* mentionned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485572/add-remote-images-to-phpspreadseet-cell?noredirect=1#comment107003049_60485572), and after reading:

- PhpSpreadseet [documentation on drawing](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#add-a-drawing-to-a-worksheet).
- PHP documentation on [file_get_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).
- PHP documentation on [file_set_contents](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-set-contents.php).

This worked for me:

```php
$image = file_get_contents('https://website.com/path/to/image');
$imageName = 'a_nice_image_name';

//You can save the image wherever you want
//I would highly recommand using a temporary directory
$temp_image=tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $imageName);
file_put_contents($temp_image, $image);

// And then PhpSpreadsheet acts just like it would do with a local image
$drawing->setPath($temp_image);
$drawing->setHeight(36);
$drawing->setWorksheet($sheet);
$drawing->setCoordinates('B15');
```

More on temporary directories in the PHP docs:

- [sys_get_temp_dir()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sys-get-temp-dir.php)
- [tempnam()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)

Answer (score 0):

Specifying coordinates for the image might help, as per the examples and the documentation

```
$objDrawing->setCoordinates('A3');
```

Note that an image isn't in a cell/column/row, but overlaid over the main sheet at the same position as that cell/column/row