# How to display images in Excel output using the phpspreadsheet library

Tags: php, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

I have developed a function to output a series of information in WordPress and I use the phpspreadsheet library to output the information. I followed the documentation of the phpspreadsheet site, but I am facing this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception: File http://persis.local/wp-content/uploads/2023/02/Thousand-Way-Long-Coat-01.jpg does not exist in E:\xampp\htdocs\persis.local\wp-content\plugins\by-products\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\ContentTypes.php:226 Stack trace: #0 E:\xampp\htdocs\persis.local\wp-content\plugins\by-products\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\ContentTypes.php(137): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\ContentTypes->getImageMimeType('http://persis.l...') #1 E:\xampp\htdocs\persis.local\wp-content\plugins\by-products\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx.php(332): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\ContentTypes->writeContentTypes(Object(PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet), false) #2 E:\xampp\htdocs\persis.local\wp-content\plugins\by-products\by-products.php(572): PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx->save('purchase_order_...') #3 E:\xampp\htdocs\persis.local\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(308): in E:\xampp\htdocs\persis.local\wp-content\plugins\by-products\vendor\phpoffice\phpspreadsheet\src\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx\ContentTypes.php on line 226

I searched a bit and made a series of changes in my code, but it didn't make any difference, the error is still there. This is my code:

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

/**
 * @throws \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Exception
 * @throws \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Exception
 */
function bp_display_purchase_order_info_callback() {
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo '<h1>Purchase Order Information</h1>';
    echo '<table class="wp-list-table widefat fixed striped">';
    echo '<thead>';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Product Photo</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Product Name</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">SKU</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Number of Purchases</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Producer Name</th>';
    echo '<th scope="col">Last Price</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    echo '</thead>';
    echo '<tbody>';

    // Query the products to retrieve their details
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => - 1,
        'orderby'        => 'modified', // Sort by the update date
        'order'          => 'DESC',     // Sort in descending order (newest to oldest)
    );


    $products = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $products->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
            $products->the_post();

            // Get product details
            $product_id    = get_the_ID();
            $product       = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            $product_name  = $product->get_name();
            $product_sku   = $product->get_sku();
            $product_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $product_id, 'thumbnail' );

            // Get custom "Purchase Quantity" field value
            $purchase_quantity = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_purchase_quantity', true );

            // Get the latest price information
            $last_price   = '';
            $vendor_name  = '';
            $price_change = '';

            if ( have_rows( 'details', $product_id ) ) {
                $rows         = get_field( 'details', $product_id );
                $last_row     = end( $rows );
                $last_price   = $last_row['price'];
                $vendor_name  = $last_row['vendor_name'];
                $price_change = $last_row['price_change'];
            }

            // Display the product only if it has a "Number of Purchases" value
            if ( $purchase_quantity > 0 ) {
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td><img src="' . $product_image . '" alt="' . $product_name . '" style="max-width: 100px;"></td>';
                echo '<td>' . $product_name . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $product_sku . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $purchase_quantity . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $vendor_name . '</td>';
                echo '<td>';

                if ( $last_price ) {
                    $price_text = '';

                    if ( ! empty( $price_change ) && strcasecmp( $price_change, 'yes' ) == 0 ) {
                        $price_text .= '<span style="color: #fff; background: #ff0000; padding: 1px 3px; font-weight: bolder;">' . $last_price . '</span>';
                    } else {
                        $price_text .= $last_price;
                    }

                    echo $price_text;
                }

                echo '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    } else {
        echo '<tr><td colspan="7">No products found.</td></tr>';
    }

    echo '</tbody>';
    echo '</table>';


    // Create a new Spreadsheet object
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
    $sheet       = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();


    // Add column headers
    $sheet->setCellValue( 'A1', 'Product Photo' );
    $sheet->setCellValue( 'B1', 'Product Name' );
    $sheet->setCellValue( 'C1', 'SKU' );
    $sheet->setCellValue( 'D1', 'Number of Purchases' );
    $sheet->setCellValue( 'E1', 'Producer Name' );
    $sheet->setCellValue( 'F1', 'Last Price' );

    // Set column headers style
    $headerStyle = $sheet->getStyle( 'A1:F1' );
    $headerStyle->getFont()->setBold( true );
    $headerStyle->getAlignment()->setHorizontal( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER );
    $headerStyle->getBorders()->getAllBorders()->setBorderStyle( \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Border::BORDER_THIN );

    $row = 2; // Start from row 2 for data

    // Loop through the products and add data to the Excel sheet
    if ( $products->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
            $products->the_post();

            // Get product details
            $product_id    = get_the_ID();
            $product       = wc_get_product( $product_id );
            $product_name  = $product->get_name();
            $product_sku   = $product->get_sku();
            $product_image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $product_id, 'thumbnail' );

            // Get custom "Purchase Quantity" field value
            $purchase_quantity = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_purchase_quantity', true );

            // Get the latest price information
            $last_price   = '';
            $vendor_name  = '';
            $price_change = '';

            if ( have_rows( 'details', $product_id ) ) {
                $rows         = get_field( 'details', $product_id );
                $last_row     = end( $rows );
                $last_price   = $last_row['price'];
                $vendor_name  = $last_row['vendor_name'];
                $price_change = $last_row['price_change'];
            }

            // Display the product only if it has a "Number of Purchases" value
            if ( $purchase_quantity > 0 ) {

                $drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
                $drawing->setName( 'Product Image' );
                $drawing->setDescription( 'Product Image' );
                $drawing->setPath( $product_image ); /* put your path and image here */
                $drawing->setCoordinates( 'A1' );
                $drawing->setOffsetX( 110 );
                $drawing->setRotation( 25 );
                $drawing->getShadow()->setVisible( true );
                $drawing->getShadow()->setDirection( 45 );
                $drawing->setWorksheet( $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet() );

                // Add data to the Excel sheet
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'A' . $row, $product_image );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'B' . $row, $product_name );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'C' . $row, $product_sku );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'D' . $row, $purchase_quantity );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'E' . $row, $vendor_name );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'F' . $row, $last_price );

                $row ++;
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    // Adjust the column widths
    foreach ( range( 'A', 'F' ) as $column ) {
        $sheet->getColumnDimension( $column )->setAutoSize( true );
    }

    // Set the filename for the Excel file
    $filename = 'purchase_order_info.xlsx';

    // Save the Excel file
    $writer = new Xlsx( $spreadsheet );
    $writer->save( $filename );

    // Output a link to download the Excel file
    echo '<p style="position: absolute;top: 75px;right: 20px;"><a class="button button-primary" href="' . $filename . '">Download Excel File</a></p>';

    echo '</div>';
}
```

I checked the codes several times and made several changes, but the problem is in the location. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What context/setup are you running this in? I am guessing that it is probably not able to resolve the `persis.local` hostname when the library tries to request those image URLs ...?

Comment: I will test these items on the local host and transfer them to the leading site.
Does this mean that the problem is that I check on the local host?

Comment: You appear to be running the whole code on your local machine, according to the path mentioned in the error messages - so I would assume if you are able to access these image URLs via your browser, it should work from within the script as well. Have you checked whether they work in your browser?

Comment: Yes, I have access to all the photos, and the photos are fully opened, I use this library to display the photo itself instead of displaying the address of the images, that is, if I have a product that is a photo of a mug, the image of the mug will be displayed. Not the address where the image is saved

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about there. I asked whether you can access the image URL from the error message above directly in your browser, yes or no?

Comment: Yes, did you read the first sentence?
I will explain the rest of my cases to you so that you understand what I want

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add remote images to PhpSpreadseet cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485572/add-remote-images-to-phpspreadseet-cell)

Comment: I used the same codes to display the image but it didn't work
In ```$drawing->setPath('/images/image-1.png');``` section, any value I put does not work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you have not specified the photo path correctly
in part :

```
// Display the product only if it has a "Number of Purchases" value
if ( $purchase_quantity > 0 ) {
```

Add the following codes:

```
         if ($product_image) {
                    $parsed_url = parse_url($product_image);
                    $absolute_path = rtrim(ABSPATH, '/') . $parsed_url['path'];

                    if (file_exists($absolute_path)) {
                        $drawing = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Drawing();
                        $drawing->setName('Product Image');
                        $drawing->setDescription('Product Image');
                        $drawing->setPath($absolute_path); // Use the absolute path here
                        $drawing->setHeight(150);
                        $drawing->setWidth(150);
                        $drawing->setCoordinates('A' . $row);
                        $drawing->setWorksheet($sheet);
                        // Set row height to accommodate the image
                        $sheet->getRowDimension($row)->setRowHeight(150);  // Adjust this based on your needs
                    } else {
                        $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $row, 'Image Not Found');
                    }
                } else {
                    $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $row, 'No Image');
                }
                // Set column width for column 'A'
                $sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(150);  // Adjust this based on your needs

                $sheet->setCellValue( 'B' . $row, $product_name );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'C' . $row, $product_sku );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'D' . $row, $purchase_quantity );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'E' . $row, $vendor_name );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'F' . $row, $last_price );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'G' . $row, $order_date );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'H' . $row, $purchase_date );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'I' . $row, $delivery_date );
                $sheet->setCellValue( 'J' . $row, $bp_description );

                $row ++;
```

It should be noted that it is no longer necessary to go to the `$sheet->setCellValue( 'A' . $row, $product_image );` section